# Flutter error com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

Tags: android, flutter

When I am trying to run my flutter app I am getting bellow error

I already tried different solutions but failed to fix this error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zza found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-20.0.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.0.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzb found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-20.0.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.0.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzc found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-20.0.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.0.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzd found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-20.0.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.0.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zze found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-20.0.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.0.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzf found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-20.0.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.0.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzh found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-20.0.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.0.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzm found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-20.0.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.0.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzo found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-20.0.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.0.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzka found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-17.5.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.5.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.2)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzkv found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-17.5.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.5.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.2)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzkw found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-17.5.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-
     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm facing a similar issue with: 
```
`jetified-firebase-iid-20.1.5-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.1.5) and jetified-firebase-messaging-23.0.5-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.5)
`
```

Comment: @felipeclopes Yes I was able to resolve this problem. And I forgot what was the solution exactly. But I think updating my dependencies in pubspec.yaml file after that `flutter clean` `flutter pub upgrade` `flutter pub get` solved my issue.